# Cannot remove or fix python-cairo - Errors were encountered while processing: python-cairo:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, dpkg

I've read multiple threads and forums but can't remove this issue. I tried removing using purge and checked this [page](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/python-cairo?type=uninstall). Let me know how to fix this. Thanks.

```
(base) seek4samurai@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove python-cairo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python-cairo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 270 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 316333 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-cairo:amd64 (1.16.2-2ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-cairo:amd64.prerm: 6: pyclean: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package python-cairo:amd64 (--remove):
 installed python-cairo:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-cairo:amd64.postinst: 6: pycompile: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-cairo:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cairo:amd64
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Packages *not fully installed* can't be removed. Try reinstalling first, i.e., use the `--reinstall` additional parameter.

Comment: I read from one thread about this issue, guess that fixed it.
Removing `python-cairo` and it's description from `/usr/lib/dpkg/status.txt` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Packages not fully installed can't be removed. Try reinstalling python-cairo and then removing it. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-cairo
sudo apt remove python-cairo
```